# Need Help ranking the poll options based on prority selection

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

Need some help in ranking poll options, tried doing by multidimensional arrays but nothing worked.

My data structure is as per below:

```
**Table** Poll

**Id** **Question** **op1**  p1  **op2** p2 **op3** p3  **op4** p4 **op5** p5

1            q1 ?          Excellent 5  Better   4  Good  3  Ok   2   Not OK 1

2            q2 ?          Sure      5   Perfect 4  Fine  3  Never 2    No  1

**Table** Answer

**id**  **poll_id**  **users_id**  **answer**  **resultOrder**
---------------------------------------------------------------


  1          1           1            Excellent     1

  2          1           1            Better        2

  3          1           1            Ok            3

  4          1           1            Good          4

  5         1           1             Not Ok         5

  6          1           2            Excellent     1

  7          1           2            Ok            2

  8          1           2            Better        3

  9          1           2            Not Ok        4

  10         1           2            Good          5
```

Each user will submit five options priorities them as per his suggestion

Option will get ranking as per counts

e.g Excellent selected for 2 times for first preference it will get 100 points and others will get 80,60,40,20 points based on their counts for all priorities.

if count ties matches points will be given on p1, p2 column in table poll

**For Example if my group by [answer] look like below  5 people voted Excellent as first preference, 4 people voted better as second preference and so on till Not Ok preferred by 1 person for fifth preference **

```
Answer     count(answer)   it should set point like this

Excellent     5                  100

Better        4                   80

Good          3                  60  

Ok            2                  40

Not Ok        1                  20
```

Hope this is possible. I tried it many ways, but no luck.

Comment: Whenever you have multiple columns for a similar field, it should ring alarm bells. Considering normalizing the `poll` table.

Comment: Yes thanks for suggestion but can't do that now as it has to go live tommarow evening will do it in next update